# Defining a variable in Go programming language

Tags: go

I am learning Go language and comes across seeing this type of variable declaration:

```
i:=1;
```

But it says that Go has static variables. i,e variables should be defined in some  way like this

```
var i int=1;
```

So what is the difference between these two methods? In the first one we don't need to indicate the data type. Why is it so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one `i := 1` is called [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations). It is a shorthand for regular [variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations) with initializer expressions but no types:

```
var IdentifierList = ExpressionList
```

You don't specify the type of `i`, but `i` will have a type based on certain rules. Its type will be automatically inferred. In this case it will be of type `int` because the initializer expression `1` is an untyped integer constant whose default type is `int`, so when a type is needed (e.g. it is used in a short variable declaration), `int` type will be deduced.

So Go is statically typed. That means variables will have a static type and values stored in them at runtime will always be of that type. Being statically typed does not mean *you* have to explicitly specify the static type, it just means variables must have a static type - decided at compile time - which condition is met even if you use short variable declaration and you don't specify it.

Note that you can also omit the type if you declare a variable with the `var` keyword:

```
var i = 1
```

In which case the type will also be deduced from the type of the initializer expression.

[Spec: Variable declaration:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations)

> If a type is present, each variable is given that type. Otherwise, each variable is given the type of the corresponding initialization value in the assignment. If that value is an untyped constant, it is first [converted](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) to its [default type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants); if it is an untyped boolean value, it is first converted to type `bool`. The predeclared value `nil` cannot be used to initialize a variable with no explicit type.

Comment: Ok., I got it now. Thanks.   So since i =1 and 1 is an integer, i will get integer as datatype. But another doubt is integer itself has int8, int16, int 64 as sub types ryt? So  will i take int8 as default here?

Comment: @HariKrishnan This expression: `1` is an **untyped** constant. If an expression is an untyped constant (and **not** a typed constant), then its **default type** is used which is `int` for untyped integer constants, as stated by the spec. If a **typed** constant is used, then obviously the type of the typed constant is used.

Answer (score 0):

Go is designed with ease of use in mind. So new variables are able to get an implicit type of the right side using the `:=` operator. Also the constant `1` for example has an implicit type in go.