# How does an untyped constant '\n' get converted into a byte when passed as method arg?

Tags: go

I was watching this talk given at FOSDEM '17 about implementing "tail -f" in Go => https://youtu.be/lLDWF59aZAo

In the author's initial example program, he creates a `Reader` using a file handle, and then uses the `ReadString` method with delimiter '\n' to read the file line by line and print its contents. I usually use `Scanner`, so this was new to me.

Program below | [Go Playground Link](https://play.golang.org/p/JaTHYAoeBb)

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fileHandle, err := os.Open("someFile.log")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
        return
    }
    defer fileHandle.Close()

    reader := bufio.NewReader(fileHandle)

    for {
        line, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
            break
        }
        fmt.Print(line)
    }

}
```

Now, `ReadString` takes a byte as its delimiter argument[https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString]

So my question is, how in the world did '\n', which is a `rune`, get converted into a `byte`? I am not able to get my head around this. Especially since `byte` is an alias for `uint8`, and `rune` is an alias for `int32`.

I asked the same question in Gophers slack, and was told that '\n' is not a `rune`, but an untyped constant. If we actually created a `rune` using '\n' and passed it in, the compilation would fail. This actually confused me a bit more.

I was also given a link to a section of the Go spec regarding Type Identity => https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity

If the program is not supposed to compile if it were an actual `rune`, why does the compiler allow an untyped constant to go through? Isn't this unsafe behaviour?

My guess is that this works due to a rule in the [Assignability section in the Go spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability), which says

> x is an untyped constant representable by a value of type T.

Since '\n' can indeed be assigned to a variable of type `byte`, it is therefore converted.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Be sure to check the official blog post regarding constants: https://blog.golang.org/constants

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR *Yes* you are correct but there's something more.

`'\n'` is an *untyped rune constant*. It doesn't have a type but a *default type* which is `int32` (`rune` is an alias for `int32`). It holds a single byte representing the literal "\n", which is the numeric value `10`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%T %v %c\n", '\n', '\n', '\n') // int32 10 (newline)
}
```

*https://play.golang.org/p/lMjrTFDZUM*

The part of the spec that answers your question lies in the [*§ Calls*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls) (emphasis mine):

> Given an expression f of function type F,
>
> ```
> f(a1, a2, … an)
> ```
>
> calls f with arguments a1, a2, … an. Except for one
>   special case, **arguments must be single-valued expressions *assignable*
>   to the parameter types of F** and are evaluated before the function is
>   called.

[*"assignable"*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) is the key term here and the part of the spec you quoted explains what it means. As you correctly guessed, among the various rules of *assignability*, the one that applies here is the following:

> x is an untyped constant representable by a value of type T.

In our case this translates to:

> '\n' is an untyped (rune) constant representable by a value of type `byte`

The fact that `'\n'` is actually converted to a byte when calling `ReadString()` is more apparent if we try passing an untyped rune constant wider than 1 byte, to a function that expects a `byte`:

```
package main

func main() {
    foo('α')
}

func foo(b byte) {}
```

*https://play.golang.org/p/W0EUZppWHH*

The code above fails with:

> tmp/sandbox120896917/main.go:9: constant 945 overflows byte

That's because `'α'` is actually 2 bytes, which means it cannot be converted to a value of type `byte` (the maximum integer a `byte` can hold is 255 while `'α'` is actually 945).

All this is explained in the official blog post, [*Constants*](https://blog.golang.org/constants).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your reading is correct. [Spec: Assignability](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) section applies here as the value you want to pass must be assignable to the type of the parameter.

When you pass the value `'\n'`, that is an untyped [constant](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) specified by a [rune literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals). It represents a number equal to the Unicode code of the `'\n'` character (which is 10 by the way). The rule you quoted applies here:

> `x` is an untyped [constant](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) representable by a value of type `T`.

Constants have a default type, which will be used when a type is "missing" from the context where the value is used. Such an example is the [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations):

```
r := '\n'
fmt.Printf("%T", r)
```

The default type of a rune literal is that: `rune`. The above code prints `int32` because the `rune` type is an alias for `int32` (they are "identical", interchangable). Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/U4wDu3Z1t5).

Now if you try to pass the variable `r` to a function which expects a value of type `byte`, it is a compile time error, because this case matches none of the assignability rules. You need explicit type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) to make such a case work:

```
r := '\n'
line, err := reader.ReadString(byte(r))
```

See related blog posts and questions:

[Spec: Constants](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants)

[The Go Blog: Constants](https://blog.golang.org/constants)

[Defining a variable in Go programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36278121/defining-a-variable-in-go-programming-language/36278207#36278207)

[Custom type passed to function as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501596/custom-type-passed-to-function-as-a-parameter/41501756#41501756)

[Why do these two float64s have different values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27819137/why-do-these-two-float64s-have-different-values/27819409#27819409)

[Does go compiler's evaluation differ for constant expression and other expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444852/does-go-compilers-evaluation-differ-for-constant-expression-and-other-expressio/39445372#39445372)